# cakePHP and Google AdSense

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, adsense

I have a problem with AdSense code within cakePHP view. I use standard cakePHP 2.X (didn't make any changes in configuration).

You can see the situation at variart.org - on the bottom/footer of this page there is a blank space. The ads just don't show up :(

Thanks for any help.

The code from AdSense is:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- new VA_responsive -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-4708089258816495"
     data-ad-slot="6497910316"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your adsense `show_ads_impl.js` is returning 403 with the following message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (OK)

The most common reasons for this is:

- Your AdSense account wasn't approved yet
- Your site was disabled to serve Ads

I recommend you to review all your preferences and your account status in AdSense to know if something is messed there.

Comment: Thanks! They found something "is not currently in compliance with our AdSense program policies" - they are too conservative :(